# Unable to do any read/write operation after executing stored procedure with hibernate current session

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, stored-procedures, callable-statement

I have seen difference in behavior when executing the below methods (contains **SQL Server Procedure**) with **Hibernate(version 5.4.2.final)** `getCurrentSession()`

```java
public List<A> notWorkingA() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.doWork(connection -> {
        try(CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{ call PROCEDURE_WITH_NO_OUTPARAM() }")){
            callableStatement.execute();
        }
    });
    CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<A> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(A.class);
    Root<A> rootObject = criteriaQuery.from(A.class);
    Predicate mainPredicate = builder.and(
            builder.equal(rootObject.get("p1"), 1),
            builder.equal( rootObject.get("p2"), "SOMEVALUE")
    );
    criteriaQuery.select(rootObject).where(mainPredicate);
    Query<A> query = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    return query.getResultList();
}

public List<A> workingA() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.doWork(connection -> {
        try(CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{ call PROCEDURE_WITH_NO_OUTPARAM() }")){
            callableStatement.execute();
        }
    });
    SessionFactoryUtils.closeSession(session);

    session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<A> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(A.class);
    Root<A> rootObject = criteriaQuery.from(A.class);
    Predicate mainPredicate = builder.and(
            builder.equal(rootObject.get("p1"), 1),
            builder.equal( rootObject.get("p2"), "SOMEVALUE")
    );
    criteriaQuery.select(rootObject).where(mainPredicate);
    Query<A> query = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    return query.getResultList();
}

public List<A> notWorkingB() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.doWork(connection -> {
        try(CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{ call PROCEDURE_WITH_OUTPARAM() }")){
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
            callableStatement.execute();
        }
    });
    CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<A> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(A.class);
    Root<A> rootObject = criteriaQuery.from(A.class);
    Predicate mainPredicate = builder.and(
            builder.equal(rootObject.get("p1"), 1),
            builder.equal( rootObject.get("p2"), "SOMEVALUE")
    );
    criteriaQuery.select(rootObject).where(mainPredicate);
    Query<A> query = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    return query.getResultList();
}

public List<A> workingB() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.doWork(connection -> {
        try(CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{ call PROCEDURE_WITH_OUTPARAM() }")){
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
            callableStatement.execute();
            log.info(callableStatement.getString(1));
        }
    });
    CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<A> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(A.class);
    Root<A> rootObject = criteriaQuery.from(A.class);
    Predicate mainPredicate = builder.and(
            builder.equal(rootObject.get("p1"), 1),
            builder.equal( rootObject.get("p2"), "SOMEVALUE")
    );
    criteriaQuery.select(rootObject).where(mainPredicate);
    Query<A> query = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

When executing `notWorkingA()` & `notWorkingB()` the line `query.getResultList()` giving the below error

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The server failed to resume the transaction. Desc:6e00000008.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:251)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:81)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:36)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$1ConnectionCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:1835)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:6276)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1794)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectionCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1840)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.rollback(SQLServerConnection.java:2043)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.rollback(NewProxyConnection.java:860)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.rollback(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:116)
    ... 49 more
```

After some debugging I got the fix for `notWorkingB()` like if it calling `callableStatement.getString(1)` as in `workingB()` it will work(but not understanding the root cause). But in the case of `notWorkingA()`, since it is procedure with no output param, I can't do this workaround here and it will work if it is using `openSession()` as in `workingA()`.

So I would like to know what exactly the root cause of this issue. Also how can I make `notWorkingA()` to work with `currentSession()` itself since the transaction is managed in the **Filter**.

**Note:**
This case was working correctly in **Hibernate 3**. Issue is coming only after migrating to **Hibernate 5**

Comment: This is just a hunch, but could that callableStatement.execute() not really be doing anything until an action member is accessed (callableStatement.getString(1)), as in Lazy Loading..Then you are expecting something to be available but it is not as you have not caused the main command to be invoked??

Comment: @RossBush Procedure is actually populating a temp table A and returning the status & error message(if any). After inserting into able procedure is calling commit. But the issue here is even after closing callableStatement, what is making the issue to cause this exception. And this same thing is working fine in hibernate 3 version.